# SSO using STS fails to login user for webtest in VSTS

Tags: webtest, windows-live-id

All,

I have a webtest for Web Performance testing, which does login prior to running other web requests in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

The login system uses STS and Windows Identity Framework to login users.  For a normal login, ie not in my webtest, there is no issue with logging in.

When I run my webtest, I get the following

ID4223: The SamlSecurityToken is rejected because the SamlAssertion.NotOnOrAfter condition is not satisfied.
NotOnOrAfter: '2/6/2012 10:52:06 PM'
Current time: '2/6/2012 11:16:01 PM'

I have used Fiddler to look at the requests and responses, but there seems to be little difference, except that I do not get the FED cookies on the webtest, but rather the error mentioned above.

What am I missing?

NOTE: the STS website is in a different timezone than the requesting webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of the fields in the request is hard coded rather than taking a value from previous http requests. I.e. the login post/response is bringing back a timecode which is ignored in favor of the time your webtest was recorded.

Comment: That was exactly the issue! Thanks